# Wrong constructor called due to implicit cast

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I am working on a project with Visual Studio 2022 with Opencv 4.6.0.
I have the following code

```
struct MyStruct
{
  MyStruct(const cv::Vec3d& a, const cv::Vec3d& b){}
  MyStruct() = default;

  cv::Vec3b a;
  cv::Vec3b b;
};

int main()
{
  int i = 0,j = 0;
  MyStruct ms(i,j);
}
```

This code is compiling but should not as the constructor called in the main() doesn't exist. The non-default constructor is called by implictly calling the constructor of *cv::Vec3b*
with *int* provided as arguments.

I don't understand this behavior. I know that for constructor with single argument it can be the case (and can be avoided with the *explicit* keyword) but it should not with two arguments.

Comment: It'll be the single argument constructors of `Vec3d` that need to be `explicit` not your constructor

Comment: `cv::Vec3d` has a single argument constructor, which is used to convert your `int`s into a `cv::Vec3d`s. See: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html#a70931c51a1f6c84bc8f1863b8f35fadc.

Comment: Your constructor needs two Vec3d type arguments, but you set int type to it.

Comment: Just a word usage note. A cast is an *explicit* type conversion. "Implicit cast" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for your answer. I always though that as the constructor has two arguments with no default value, the compiler will throw me an error for wrong type.  It seems that it first convert the argument by calling the Vec3d constructor before checking this ...

Comment: No, implicit conversions do only apply to single argument non-explicit constructors but that doesn't mean they don't happen for each argument in a multiple argument constructor (or any other function call)